# Matlab cat() function: index exceeds matrix dimensions

Tags: matlab, indexing, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate an array of numbers from 1->(a-1) + (a+1)->n.

I was using the cat function

```
cat(2, 1:a-1, a+1:n)
```

but I am getting the error

```
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
```

Unless I am completely mistaken, I am just trying to concatenate two matrices of numbers so I'm not quite sure why I'm getting this error.

I'm trying to accomplish this:

```
>> a = 3;
>> n = 10;
>> cat(2, 1:a-1, a+1:n)
ans = 
    [1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Is this the wrong way to do it? Any idea why this error is coming up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have a variable called `cat` in your workspace?

```
>> cat(2, 2:3, 4:6)                   # this works fine
ans =
     2     3     4     5     6
>> cat = 1:3;                         # introduce the variable 'cat'
>> cat(2, 2:3, 4:6)                   # now it breaks
??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
```

Comment: Actually yes, its a struct. Is there any way I can do this without changing the name of the variable?  (I did not write this, just trying to debug for someone and want to change as little as possible).

Comment: The best thing to do, by a long way, is to change the name of the variable. Tell your friend that this will be better in the long run. Letting your variables share names with built-in Matlab functions is a really, *really* bad idea.

If they really don't want to change it, you could use `horzcat(1:a-1, a+1:n)` instead of `cat(2, 1:a-1, a+1:n)`, or just use Matlab's array concatenation syntax: `[1:a-1, a+1:n]`.

Comment: I just did a find/replace. Works fine now. Thanks so much

Comment: @user1653208 No problem. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Feel free to use the upvote/accept buttons as you see fit :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a variable named `cat` in the workspace. The clean way is, of course, to rename the variable: If you have a sufficiently recent version of Matlab (R2012x, I think), you can replace `cat` in the first line it gets assigned (select the variable to see the gray ticks to the right of the window, indicating where the variable occurs in the function), and use `shift+enter` to replace all occurrences. Or you can use the Find/Replace all function (make sure you only replace words, not substrings, though).

If you cannot replace the existing variable name, you can use square brackets for catenation along the first and/or second dimension:

```
cat(2,a,b)
```

is equivalent to

```
[a,b]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, the concatenation you're trying to accomplish can also be achieved like so:

```
R = 1:n;
R = R(R ~= a)
```

I personally think this looks cleaner than

```
R = [1:a-1 a+1:n]
```

but that's personal; I always feel a little confusion towards something like `1:a-1>5` (is it `((1:a)-1)>5` or `(1:(a-1))>5` or `(1:a)-(1>5)` or ...). I just always have to think for a second, whereas I understand my solution instantly.